# How to open a TXT File with a specific path in html with iframe

Tags: javascript, html

My Problem is I want to make a program that reads Text files but I don't know how to specify the path I have a program already this looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Textdateien lesen</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
 :-webkit-full-screen {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

:-moz-full-screen {
 background-color: #FFF;
}

:-ms-fullscreen {
 background-color: #FFF;
}

:fullscreen {
 background-color: #FFF;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>Text</h1><br>
<p>Letztes mal Taschengeld bekommen am:</p><button onclick="fullscreen()">Fullscreen</button>
<div id="list"><iframe src="TXT.txt" width=200 height=400 frameborder=0 id="frame"></iframe></div>

</center>
<script>
    function fullscreen() {
        var i = document.getElementById("frame");

// go full-screen
if (i.requestFullscreen) {
    i.requestFullscreen();
} else if (i.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    i.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (i.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    i.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (i.msRequestFullscreen) {
    i.msRequestFullscreen();
}
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a txt file in my folder but I don't know how I can specify a path like: "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Programmiersachen/HTML/Projekte/Mit HTML Hacken/TXT.txt"

Comment: Pretty sure that won't work. You'll have to rename the .txt file to .html

Comment: You cannot do that from client side(it should be a security issue...imagine if with simple html and javascript, every site could access our local filesystem!!). That's why you should use a server side language like php, and putting the file in the server folder

Comment: By the way: I want to hack/trick the computersystem of my school because it is programmed like this that you cant chat or copy files from the other guy and i want to make it that i read a file from the computer of the guy on the other side of the class or something :D

Comment: @pmahomme No, it works. I just ran it on my computer here. What do you need kid? If you give the full path to the `src` attribute in the iframe it shows up but I get the feeling you want to choose txt files at will? ETA: Nvm just read that comment. Will think about that for a bit. @Hackerman pretty much surmised why you can't do this. Nice try though!

Comment: When i am giving the filepath in the src field it does not work or did i type something wrong because it says that (c) is not a valid adress

Comment: So basically you're asking us to help you cheat on tests? Just study, so you can write that awesome script yourself soon.;)

Comment: @Mike Yes i want to choose a file from a specified path because with the <input type="file"> thing im pretty sure it wont work because it would say "You cant acces this Part" or something like that

Comment: @Shilly No were writing Tests in Word :D

Comment: This can be be done on a local computer, preferably using a relative path in the src=...

But a networked system or a website running in (eg) IIS *should* prevent this happening for the obvious security reasons stated above. 

If hacking was that easy we'd all be doing it - it isn't and it shouldn't be.

Comment: @TonyDuffill Just right now i want it to work on my Computer

Comment: OK - the iframe src='...' can be any file that your *browser* has permission to read, but you may need to specify a relative path - eg: ../../folder/file. I don't think it matters if it's a .txt file but might be wrong, but the file is assumed to be formatted as HTML. Try it first with a simple Test.htm file in the same folder as your main .htm file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the problem is that i typed it in wrong this is how it will work

```
<iframe src="file:///C:\Users\Nils\Desktop\Programmiersachen\HTML\Projekte\Mit_HTML_Hacken\TXT.txt" width=200 height=200 frameborder=0 id="frame">
```

i hope this will help others :D

Comment: If you are doing a project, you should consider keeping the text file in the same directory as the html file.